# Real-time output of command that not take up current prompt position?

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

I have command: `ps -o pid,user,%cpu,command | head -n 30`

I want to print output of above command and have it updated but keep print out at the same of previous output without refreshing the whole terminal (alacritty).

Basically the purpose is to run a script and observe change of ps command in real time but not messing up current prompt position and should not refresh the how terminal (that can cause flicker).

I tried `watch` command but it will swallow the whole terminal/tmux's pane.

I also tried tput but can't get it work.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Can you explain why `watch` isn't what you need? What's the problem with its taking up the terminal, you want it to be showing the output so you can't use that terminal anyway.

Comment: The idea is not messing up the prompt, preserve the current look of terminal. It may not feeling important for most of people but I really want to have this or a way to preserve position of prompt.

Comment: The prompt isn't affected in any way. As for the terminal, that is returned to its previous state as soon as you exit `watch` with Ctrl+C. Isn't that exactly what you want?

Comment: If using `tmux` or `screen`, it sounds like a better approach would be to run that `watch ps` in a separate tmux/screen pane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the terminal has at least 30 lines below the cursor¹, and your terminal supports those escape sequences, you could use the `sc` (save cursor) and `rc` (restore cursor) escape sequences:

```
tput sc
while true; do
  tput ed
  ps -o pid,user,%cpu,command | head -n 30
  tput rc
  sleep 1
done
```

(see also `echoti sc` or `$terminfo[sc]` in `zsh` if your `tput` doesn't support `sc`/`rc`/`ed`...).

To hide the cursor while that's running and clear the bottom of the screen when interrupted for shells that don't do that already before each prompt, you could make it.

```
my_processes() (
  trap 'tput rc; tput ed; tput cnorm; exit' EXIT INT
  tput sc; tput civis
  while true; do
    tput ed
    ps -o pid,user,%cpu,command | head -n 30
    tput rc
    sleep 1
  done
)
```

You can probably reduce the flickering by reducing the delay between the `ed` sequence and the `ps` output with:

```
my_processes() (
  for c in sc rc ed cnorm civis; do eval "$c=\$(tput $c)"; done

  trap 'printf %s "$rc$ed$cnorm"; exit' EXIT INT

  printf %s "$sc$civis"

  while true; do
    printf %s "$ed$(ps -o pid,user,%cpu,command | head -n 30)$rc"
    sleep 1
  done
)
```

Those `terminfo` capabilities are described in the `terminfo(5)` man pages:

- `sc`: save current cursor position
- `rc`: restore cursor to position of last `save_cursor`:
- `ed`: clear to end of screen
- `civis`: make cursor invisible
- `cnorm`: make cursor appear normal (undo `civis`/`cvvis`).
- `cuu <n>`¹: cursor up `<n>` lines

(in `zsh`, you can skip declaring all those `$sc` / `$rc`... variables and use `$terminfo[sc]`...)

In `zsh`, you could also use its scheduler to show that `ps` output in the zle message area, while still being able to use the shell (though that'd make completion harder to use):

```
zmodload zsh/sched
my-processes() {
  if [[ $1 = stop ]]; then
    sched -$zsh_scheduled_events[(i)*:$0]
  else
    if {zle} zle -M "$(ps -o pid,user,%cpu,command | head -n 30)"
    sched +1 $0
  fi
}
```

Run `my-processes` to start and `my-processes stop` to stop. You can toggle it on and off with a key press with:

```
toggle-my-processes() {
  local event
  if (( event = zsh_scheduled_events[(I)*:my-processes] )); then
    sched -$event
    zle redisplay
  else
    my-processes
  fi
}
zle -N toggle-my-processes
bindkey '\ep' toggle-my-processes
```

(here bound to the `ESC` `p` character sequence, generally sent by terminals when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>)

---

<sup>¹ you could run `yes '' | head -n30; tput cuu 30` to ensure there are 30 lines below the cursor if you wanted to. That may not be necessary though if you have fewer processes to report.</sup>

Comment: It has a flick of cursor at top left under cursor, and bottom left after last line of output, how to remove/hide/disable it? Thanks for quick answer.


It also not clean up the output cleanly after I press `Ctrl-c` to interrupt, how to have it back to normal?

Comment: Howto `my-processes` work? I have the function in `test.sh` and call `my-processes` after the function declaration also, but run `test.sh` give empty result. and with `my_processes`, it still has one empty line after I press `Ctrl-c`, how to remove it? And how can I bind it to a keybinding and keep current position of prompt intact after press `Ctrl-c`?

Comment: @TuyenPham, `my-processes` needs to be defined as a function in the current shell as it uses the shell's scheduler and line editor. So either enter that code at the prompt or add it to your `~/.zshrc` or other startup file.

Comment: `my-processes` flicker a lot when I have it in `.zshrc`. `my_processes` is less flicker, and how to have it clean to after current prompt position? And how to have it map to a combined key like `Alt-p`?

Comment: @TuyenPham flickering is probably down to your terminal emulator and even possibly to your compositing window manager if you have one. It doesn't flicker for me in `screen` inside `xterm` on Debian with openbox WM. See edit for toggling with a key.

Comment: I use `xterm-256color` as `$TERM` but still flicker. Howto have `my_processes` clean up to after current prompt and map to a combined keys? Thanks.

Comment: I had tested `my-processes` under `zsh -f -i` and indeed not flicker, but with other `ps` command that have busy update I believe, it flicker.

Comment: The value of `$TERM` is used as key in the terminfo database, it doesn't really identify what terminal emulator you're using. Inside `tmux`, I'd expect you get a `tmux` related value.

Comment: @TuyenPham `my_processes` is just a standalone command you run (you could also make it a script instead of a function), not something embedded in your shell, it wouldn't make much sense to bind a key to it.

Comment: Hi, with the second `my_processes`, where should I put `tput ed` to clean up line to after prompt and does it cause flicker?

Comment: @TuyenPham see edit. `tput ed`  tells the terminal to clear the screen from the current cursor position to the end of the screen. If at that point the terminal emulator chooses to redraw the screen with that section cleared, you'll see a frame with that section blanked, and then when the output of ps is sent to the terminal, that will change again, which is likely what you call *flicker*.

Comment: I mean in 2nd `my_processes`, `printf %s "$ed$(ps -o pid,user,%cpu,command | head -n 30)$rc"` did not clear screen next under prompt when you press `ctrl-c` to exit.