# Awareness of text under prompt?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh

Continue of this question: [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/656714/256195)

In 2nd `my_processes` function:

```
my_processes() (
  for c in sc rc ed cnorm civis; do eval "$c=\$(tput $c)"; done

  trap 'printf %s "$rc$ed$cnorm"; exit' EXIT INT

  printf %s "$sc$civis"

  while true; do
    printf %s "$ed$(ps -o pid,user,%cpu,command | head -n 30)$rc"
    sleep 1
  done
)
```

If I use another ps command that contains long list of processes (e.g: no `head`) in a small wide tmux pane, that would cause text in terminal messed up and some time I resize tmux pane that also cause text messed up.

I current chose above function over `zle` as `zle`'s cost is `flicker`.

How to have text display only in a fixed wide of screen/pane (e.g: 10 lines) and be able to go back to its state in event of resize pane for instance.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

Within GNU `screen`, you can run:

```
screen -X eval split focus 'resize 10' 'screen watch -n1 ps' 'focus prev'
```

To run `watch ps` in a 10 line high pane if that's you're looking for.

Note that it runs `watch` in a new terminal emulator and attached to a new pty device, so `ps` without arguments like that will only show the processes in that terminal, you'll likely want to adapt the `ps` line so it shows the processes you want it to show.

Maybe something like:

```
screen -X eval split \
               focus \
               'resize 10' \
               "screen watch -n1 ps -t $TTY -o pid,user,%cpu,args" \
               'focus prev'
```

Comment: Offload from current shell is not what I'm looking for, but thanks.